# Android UnknownHostException with .local host

Tags: android, exception, local, httpurlconnection, unknown-host

I experience a problem in my android app and wonder if you know a solution.
I use HttpUrlConnection and if i connect to the host `myhost.local` (via http and https both is possible) everything works just fine. But if I want to connect to the host `myhost` I get following exception:

`java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host insert_host_here: No address associated with hostname`

If I use the browser on my phone both `myhost.local` and my `myhost` can be accessed.
And if I type `$ host myhost` into terminal i get following answer

`user@machine:$ host myhost.local
myhost.local has address 192.168.0.115
user@machine:$ host myhost
myhost.local has address 192.168.0.115`

There is no proxy in between or something. Its the direct answer from the dns.
Some idea what it could be?

Greetz

btw: internet permission is granted / device has access to wifi / Version on tested device is Android 4.3 / Emulator shows same result

Comment: Dns lookup has failed.

Comment: Why not just use the real IP address (192.168.0.115)? If you use emulator, see botzek13's answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost? I had a similar problem even though I was not even using an emulator.
[Accessing Localhost from the Android Emulator](http://blogs.adobe.com/jtalbot/2010/12/07/accessing-localhost-from-the-android-emulator/)